# Replicate SNS Topic subscription from one device end point to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I have an android device that is registered to an SNS Platform Application. So it is a platform endpoint (in terms of aws sns). It has subscribed a total of 20 Sns Topics.

If I have another device (Android or Iphone), which is also an SNS platform endpoint, I would like it to be subscribed to same SNS topics.

Basically, I want to subscribe sns topics from one device. And if I install this application to another device, I want all of my subscription to be replicated on that other device as well. I hope I made my self clear.

I am using AWS SDK for Asp.net core.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I'm only a little familiar with the process, but I think that the app running on the iPhone/Android device has to request a unique ID from Apple/Google to receive notifications. Thus, it's not just a matter of replicating the subscriptions on AWS -- you would need your app to make requests to the messaging providers.

Comment: I know we need valid GCM/FCM token that are used to create SNS Platform endpoint. And topics are subscribed by those endpont ids (ie. Platform Endpoint Arn). But if I use the app in another device, it will have its own Endpoint Arn. I would like all of those topics to be subscribed by this another device as well. I just want to know if it has already been done by some body and if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially for GCM another device would require another subscription.

The logic below will not work automatically **unless** you program it in your application.

> Basically, I want to subscribe sns topics from one device. And if I install this application to another device, I want all of my subscription to be replicated on that other device as well. I hope I made my self clear.

Please check this example in [mobile-platform-endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-platform-endpoint.html) documentation, it is not the same scenario but can be used as reference.

Comment: Programming the application to copy subscription to another device is my only option for now. But i wanted to know if AWS itself provides such api feature. A feature to copy subscription of one PlatformEndpoint to another? I could do it myself, but if AWS has provided it, then i figured it would be a better approach.

Comment: As of today there is no option to copy the subscription from one device to the other.